# Change Mercurial's history so that add/delete becomes a rename

Tags: mercurial

I renamed a file and committed the change. Mercurial recorded it as an add and a delete. Now, a week later, I wish I had known to "rename" the file so that the repository would let me follow the file's history across that change.

Is there anything I can do now, after the fact, to change the history and link the "two" files as though I had renamed them?